# How do you set the coverage in PacBio's Sequel II?

Tags: assembly, coverage, pacbio

I am reading the [Whole Genome Sequencing for *de novo* Assembly Best Practices](https://www.pacb.com/wp-content/uploads/Application-Brief-Whole-genome-sequencing-for-de-novo-assembly-Best-Practices.pdf)

> - Use the Sequel II or IIe System and SMRT® Cell 8M to sequence to desired coverage depth for complexity
>   of genome
> - 10- to 15-fold coverage per haplotype recommended

First of all Wikipedia shows different definitions for the term [haplotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplotype). Which one applies here?

Second while the recommendations state to use `10- to 15-fold` coverage per haplotype I find myself confused about how I would know the [haplotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplotype) beforehand.

From what I understand of [haplotype-estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplotype_estimation) I would need the sequenced data first.

How would I go about this when wanting to do a *de novo* assembly of a species that has no published assembly of any close relatives? That means the only information I would have at that point is the C-value of the species to be sequenced.

Or better, how does the Sequel II figure out the number of haplotypes for achieving the desired fold-coverage?

I hope I'm in the right SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They just want to know the ploidy of the sample. In a diploid sample, e.g. humans, there are two haplotypes. This is mostly important for haplotype resolution (i.e. get the two full genomes in a diploid).

Note that elsewhere in the brochure that you link it writes:

> Fast and efficient assembly of even
> the largest genomes with haplotype
> resolution of complex polyploids

If you are working with a diploid species, that translates to 20-30X coverage. That seems low to me for the older tech of CLR/Sequel sequencing, but they are the experts.

Different recommendations posted [here](https://pacbio.gs.washington.edu/) by a service provider suggest 40-50X for structural variant analysis, which seems more reasonable.

Comment: There are still situations where I might not know the ploidity due to a lack of data. At least for now I was not able to find any data on either phylum: Cnidaria or  the class: Scyphozoa or the order: Rhizostomeae. Or in the case of *Sequoia sempervirens* how did they estimate the ploidity in advance?  Thanks for the insights!

Comment: @ilamengl I think that there are some methods you can look into: 1) karyotype analysis, 2) computational tools, here is one example: https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-018-2128-z

Comment: Additionally, there is a ploidy database which does appear to have cnidarians: https://cromanpa94.github.io/ACC/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to reconstruct all haplotypes, you can sequence to ~30X regardless of ploidy.

Comment: I would agree for recent autopolyploids, but probably will be less true for polyploids with divergent haplotypes (e.g. allopolyploids).

Comment: @KamilSJaron There is not a good way to assemble those genomes for the moment and therefore few know what coverage is needed anyway. 30X would still be a good starting point.